# Change Author in excel generated by Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

i need to change the author name of the generated excel by apache poi in java. Currently the author name of all generated by apache is "Apache POI", i need to change it. can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advanced.[Generated by Apache poi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVizy.png)

Comment: Which file format(s) is this for? The exact code differs slightly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HSSFWorkbook` is a [POIDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/POIDocument.html) which has [SummaryInformation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hpsf/SummaryInformation.html).

`XSSFWorkbook` is a [POIXMLDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.html) which has [POIXMLProperties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLProperties.html) - [POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties.html).

Code to set author (aka creator) for both `XSSF` and `HSSF`:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelAuthor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String author = "Axel Richter";

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  workbook.createSheet(); 

  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   ((XSSFWorkbook)workbook).getProperties().getCoreProperties().setCreator(author); 
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   ((HSSFWorkbook)workbook).createInformationProperties();
   ((HSSFWorkbook)workbook).getSummaryInformation().setAuthor(author);
  }

  String fileName = (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook)?"Excel.xlsx":"Excel.xls";
  try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName) ) {
   workbook.write(out);
  }
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```